# Bayesian Gaussian mixture - is my prior correct?

Tags: normal-distribution, prior, posterior, gaussian-mixture-distribution, mixture-distribution

I'd like to sample from the Bayesian Posterior of a Gaussian mixture model, but I am not sure about the correct Bayesian formulation of the latter. Is the following correct?

I consider the 1-dimensional setting and want to work with a $K$-component mixture.
I start with artificially generated data and want to learn the known parameters of the GM from the data.
For chosen $\boldsymbol{\mu}:=(\mu_1,...\mu_K)$, $\boldsymbol{\sigma^2}:=(\sigma_1^2,...,\sigma_K^2)$, and $\boldsymbol{\phi}:=(\phi_1,...,\phi_K)$, I generate the data from the likelihood
$$
p(x|\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{\sigma},\boldsymbol{\phi})=\sum_{i=1}^{K}\frac{\phi_i}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma_i^2}} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu_i)^2}{2\sigma_i^2}}$$ with $\sum_i \phi_i=1$.
$x\in \mathbb{R}$ denotes a single data point here.

I choose the prior distributions as
\begin{eqnarray}
\boldsymbol{\phi}|\boldsymbol{\delta} & \sim & {\rm Dir}(\boldsymbol{\delta}),\label{eq:1D_gaussmix_prior1}\\
\mu_{i}|\sigma_{i}^{2},\mu_{0},\lambda & \sim & \mathcal{N}\big(\mu_{0},\lambda\sigma_{i}^{2}\big),\\
\sigma_{i}^{2}|\alpha,\beta & \sim & \Gamma^{-1}(\alpha,\beta),\label{eq:1D_gaussmix_prior2}
\end{eqnarray} where $\Gamma^{-1}$ denotes the inverse Gamma distribution.
The prior hyperparameters are  $\mu_0\ge0$, $\alpha>0$, $\beta>0$, $\lambda>0$, and $\boldsymbol{\delta}:=(\delta_1,...,\delta_K)$ with $\delta_i>0$.
The total prior is then given by
$$
p(\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{\sigma},\boldsymbol{\phi}|\mu_0,\alpha, \beta, \lambda, \boldsymbol{\delta})=p(\boldsymbol{\phi}|\boldsymbol{\delta})\prod_{i=1}^{K}p(\mu_{i}|\sigma_{i}^{2},\mu_{0},\lambda)p(\sigma_{i}^{2}|\alpha,\beta),
$$
where I pick $\alpha=\beta=\lambda=1$, $\mu_0=0$, and $\boldsymbol{\delta}=(1,...,1)$.

Is this setup correct thus far?

Comment: Using a Dirichlet prior for the mixture weights seems sensible to me. I don't fully understand your notation, but using a Normal-Inverse-Gamma Distribution (which I think is what you're trying to say?) for the joint distribution of $(\mu_{i}, \sigma^{2}_{i})$ is a pretty standard thing to do too. The only thing I'd say on this, is that the normal inverse gamma distribution is usually used because it's conjugate to the normal likelihood. But once you move to mixture models, I don't believe there's an analytical solution to your posterior so this benefit is diminished

Comment: Yes, I believe the product of my priors for $\mu_i$ and $\sigma_i$ should just become the Normal-Inverse-Gamma distribution. Thank you! For Posterior sampling using an MCMC method, I only use the log-posterior which does seem to admit a closed-form solution (albeit with ugly terms), as long as one is free to discard additive terms that are constant in the parameters to estimate... It's just that my code does not seem to converge, and I am not sure where the issue might be... Are there any good resources for posterior sampling of a mixture model?

Comment: Are you sure there's an analytical solution? The Gaussian mixture model is the textbook example of when you should be using Variational Inference

Comment: Any proper prior is acceptable in this setting while most improper priors lead to improper posteriors. See our paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.01178 for a case of valid improper prior.

Comment: @gazza89: Even with mixture models, one does not have to use variational inference, as exact sampling via MCMC algorithms is feasible.

Comment: @gazza89 The prior densities have analytical expressions (except for the occasional gamma function, but the latter is only a normalization constant and depends only on the hyperparameters), so the log-posterior can be written down as well.

Comment: @Xi'an. I just try to run an HMC-like scheme on the resulting posterior. How do I make sure that the constraints on the parameters remain satisfied during sampling, eg. $\sum_i \phi=1$? At first I thought that the choice of the priors would ensure this, but I just realize that this is not true.

Comment: You can either write$$\Phi_i=\eta_i\big/\sum_j \eta_j$$with the $\eta_j$'s independent Gammas, or remove one component of $\mathbf\Phi$ in order to run HMC on $$0\le\sum_{j=1}^{K-1}\Phi_j\le 1$$

Comment: @Xi'an I don't quite understand these recommendations. Do you have any reference where this might be explained? In you second suggestion, there are still constraints that need to be satisfied, no?

Comment: The Stan manual has an entry on mixtures: https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_27/stan-users-guide/mixture-modeling-chapter.html. Else, check our [handbook.](https://amzn.to/43om4sA)